# Add an existing file to a web deploy package in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

I am currently using web deploy to create a deployment package to a folder. However, I have .bat file that needs to be also published to the deployment folder that stores the .zip package.

My question is thus, how can I achieve using visual studio?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Include the file in your project in Visual Studio.

Remember to set the Build Action to `Content` in the properties window when you've clicked on the file.

The file will be copied to the output directory when you publish or build your project.

Comment: Hello Patrick, thank you for the reply, however this doesn't copy the file to the folder that the webdeploy package is been published to.

Comment: Hm, okay. This is otherwise the usual way to include files when publishing your web projects. I have successfully had a file copied to a folder using this method when publishing a project.

Comment: The Fullpath properties of the file doesn't point to the folder of the of the web deploy package instead shows the folder path to the web project itself

Comment: Well, yeah. It's in your development folder when you develop. When you publish it's copied to the output directory. I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean..

Comment: When you set up publishing settings in visual studio for a web app project, you have a package location to which the .zip package will be published to.